# OpenLayers 4.6.4 Add / Remove layer event

Tags: openlayers

Is there an event that is triggered when a layer is added / removed from the map?

I saw something through the map.getLayers() group but it only seems to fired the "changed" event and doesn't contain what layer was added or removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `propertychange` event on `layers`. it's triggered when the `layer`'s property changed.

```
map.getLayers().on("propertychange", function(e) {
    // triggered when layer added or removed
});
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRwWLg

or set `change` event on each `layer`

```
layer.on("change", function(e) {
    // then is sure what layer triggers the event
});
```

Comment: map.getLayers().on("add",function(e){}); does the trick. Was pretty sure I tried that last night and it failed to trigger for me.